# Write a program that tells the user when they will turn 64

Tags: python, string, function

How do I get the name and number of years into the string in my print statement?

```
USER_NAME = str(input("Enter your name: "))

USER_AGE = int(input("Enter your age: "))

def ageDifference(age):

    age_difference = (int(64 - age))
    print(str("Hello {:s}, you will turn 64 in {:d} years."))

ageDifference(USER_AGE)
```

Comment: Consider taking a Python tutorial. At the very least, start by searching the internet instead of asking a question on SO. "string formatting" or "string interpolation" would be good searches to start with.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass both name and age into the function arguments, and use string format function to add the parameters to print.

```
def ageDifference(name, age):

    age_difference = (int(64 - age))
    print(str("Hello {0}, you will turn 64 in {1} years.").format(name, age))
```

And call the function as `ageDifference(USER_NAME, USER_AGE)`